# Can't find my integrated camera anymore

Tags: windows-xp, lenovo-laptop, camera, integrated-camera

I formatted my Lenovo Ideapad S10e and installed Windows XP and all the drivers that I need, but I can't find the integrated camera. I used to be able to find it in My Computer. In the beginning, I thought that it was just a mistake or something so I reformatted the laptop again. After the 2nd reformatting, I'm still having the same issues and I don't know what to do or what the problem is.

Why am I not able to see the integrated camera anymore?

Comment: Have you perchance checked DeviceManager for Yellow Question Marks or Exclamation Points?

Comment: you're right, i checked it, and i found a yellow mark (unknown Device), i enabeld, disabled the device, i checked for any updates, But still uknown , what should i do Now ?

Comment: @user325258 Right click the device in Device Manager, click Properties. Click the Details tab, and select the Hardware IDs property. Copy the first value entry and paste it in comments.

Comment: You may also want to read https://superuser.com/questions/637426/i-installed-windows-and-one-of-my-devices-isnt-working

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the application for the camera, which should be on the Lenovo website.

Remember, drivers are different to applications, even though sometimes the application may sometimes include the driver.